# video finish before its real time in android

Tags: android, video

> this is video playing class

```
 public class CustomVideo extends VideoView {
        public   VideoView viewHolder ;

    public boolean flag;
    Uri video;


 public  void playVideo(final Activity activity,VideoView resource, final int path,final ImageView image1,final ImageView  image2,final ImageButton button,final ImageButton button1, int id) {

                    viewHolder=resource;

                    viewHolder = (VideoView) activity.findViewById(id);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button.setClickable(false);
                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setClickable(false);
    //          viewHolder.setZOrderOnTop(false);
    //          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(504,279);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.imageView_bg_plain);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.imageView_bg_plain);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.imageView_bg_plain);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.imageView_bg_plain);
                //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    //          params.setMargins(0, 98, 0, 0);
                viewHolder.setLayoutParams(params);
                viewHolder.invalidate();
                viewHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.bringToFront();

                 video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + activity.getPackageName() + "/" + path);
                // introVideo.setMediaController(mediaController);
                viewHolder.setVideoURI(video);
                viewHolder.requestFocus();
                viewHolder.start();

                viewHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        button.setEnabled(true);
                        button.setClickable(true);
                        button1.setEnabled(true);
                        button1.setClickable(true);
    //                    viewHolder.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                        viewHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });

            }
```

> this custom method i call to display video in each and every activity
>   , i have around 50 activity which play video from this method & class.
>   but problem is video finish before its real time.
>
> my XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/letter_lesson_screen2"
    android:id="@+id/rid"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Letter_lesson1_activity" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/bar_alphabet"
        android:id="@+id/bar_alphabet"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="7dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linelay_bar_alphabet"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bar_alphabet"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" >
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_back"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/but_back" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imgbutton_help"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/help1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imgbutton_home"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_letter_pervious"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgbutton_help"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/previous" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_letter_next"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbutton_help"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_letter_rewind"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgbutton_help"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton_letter_pervious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_letter_forward"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton_letter_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fwd" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_width="500dp" />
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_width="500dp" />
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView_letter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_bg_plain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="279dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:layout_width="504dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_line" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_letter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/b_letter" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_bg_lines"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="279dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:layout_width="504dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_line" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_letter_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ball" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_cons"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b_cons" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_2letter"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/b_cons" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_help"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="onclick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/helpscreen1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_2_letter"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_cons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please give me soultion as soon as possible , thanks in advance.

Comment: set PreparedListener to your videoview and there start your videoview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using VideoView.setOnPreparedListener, and start the video from there.

Although I find it way better solution to implement your own sorta VideoView, just create your own MediaPlayer, bind a SurfaceView to it, add MediaController if needed, I created my own button controls aswell as a seekbar. Create your own holder (you can get it from the SurfaceView) and craete your Callback to the holder.

Just google this approach for more info, there was some nice tutorial about it, I simply find it way more realiable than this VideoView shizzle. Also, you can use setDataSource from MediaPlayer which you cant use on VideoView.

Either way if you use the approach I mentioned or the one you already used, remmeber to use prepare() method

Comment: Mac_Focha i add setOnPreparedListener , but still video is not complete .problem not solve